# Binding 2 textboxes with calculated ratio

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a model that contains a HorsePower and a Kilowatt property

1 HP = 0.745 KW

I then have 2 textboxes where i want to update 'the other' with the calculated value.

eg: if i input '100' into the bound HP textbox, i want the KW textbox to update with '74,5'
and vise versa : 74,5 into KW -> updates HP to 100

one solution i figured, would be to bind to only 1 property, eg: HP and then use a value converter for the KW textbox (and then update KW on property changed)

is there another way to do this ?

Comment: "*is there another way to do this*" - sure there is, but binding to a single property with an optional Binding Converter would be a typical approach in WPF. If for some reason you need to have two view model properties, they could obviously update each other in their setters.

Answer (score -2):

You will need a binding converter like this:

```
  public class MinusValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                return 100 - System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }//END Convert 

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }//END ConvertBack 

    }//END class ValueToCurrentConverter : IValueConverter
```

And XAML:

```
        <TextBox Name="tbHorsepower" Text="8"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=tbHorsepower, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource SubstractFrom100}}" IsReadOnly="True">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <local1:MinusValueConverter x:Key="SubstractFrom100"/>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
```

[image]

(Your textboxes will most likely look different)

Comment: Note that ConvertBack has to be implemented in this scenario. Besides that, it doesn't answer the question of how to do it in a way *other* than with a Binding Converter.